# Standard python interpreter has a vi command mode?

Tags: python, vi

I was working a bit in the python interpreter (python 2.4 on RHEL 5.3), and suddenly found myself in what seems to be a 'vi command mode'. That is, I can edit previous commands with typical vi key bindings, going left with h, deleting with x...

I love it - the only thing is, I don't know how I got here (perhaps it's through one of the modules I've imported: pylab/matplotlib?).

Can anyone shed some light on how to enable this mode in the interpreter?

Comment: More recent answers provided here that helped me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636124/how-do-i-make-vi-editing-mode-work-in-irb-when-using-rvm

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ctrl-Alt-J switches from Emacs mode to Vi mode in [readline programs](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC22).

Alternatively add "set editing-mode vi" to your ~/.inputrc

Comment: Doesn't work for me -- just seems to produce a <return>.  I'm on a mac; does that make a difference?

Comment: For anyone having enough rep to add to this answer, here's a link to the readline docs: http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC22 ...so for emacs-editing-mode hit C-e, and for vi-editing-mode hit M-C-j

Comment: @JohnFouhy I'm having the same issue. And `set editing-mode vi` in my `~/.inputrc` isn't helping, either.

Answer (score 35):

This kind of all depends on a few things.

First of all, the python shell uses readline, and as such, your `~/.inputrc` is important here. That's the same with psql the PostgreSQL command-line interpreter and mysql the MySQL shell. All of those can be configured to use vi-style command bindings, with history etc.

`<ESC>` will put you into vi mode at the python shell once you've got your editing mode set to vi

You may need the following definition in your `~/.inputrc`

```
set editing-mode vi
```

**OSX info**

OSX uses libedit which uses ~/.editrc. You can *man editrc* for more information.

For example, to mimick  a popular key combination which searches in your history, you can add the following to your .editrc

```
bind "^R" em-inc-search-prev
```

Comment: did a line in your answer go missing, just before "will put you..."? thanks!

Comment: Wow.  Not only did I not know this, I didn't even know there was anything there to know!

Comment: Thanks, both for the answer and for fixing the missing ESC in it. This is great info, but I'm accepting arcanex' answer because it explains what happened in my mysterious case... (I didn't have any .inputrc file)

Comment: On MAC OS X - I still had problems after all the above suggestions. The answer provided here fixed my issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636124/how-do-i-make-vi-editing-mode-work-in-irb-when-using-rvm  In summary, adding both bind -v to .editrc, and set editing-mode vi to inputrc worked.

Comment: For macOS, the command to add to .editrc is "bind -v". In my testing with Python 3 from Apple, python.org, and Homebrew, it was not necessary to use .inputrc

Answer (score 9):

For Mac OS X 10.10.3, python2.7, `vi` mode can be configured by placing `bind -v` in `~/.editrc`.  The last few paragraphs of the man page hint at this.

Comment: An important note is that this works even for MacPorts `python`, which does *not* mention `~/.editrc` in the manpage. Even if you set up `~/.inputrc` correctly, MacPorts `python` will not work as you expect. You *need* the `~/.editrc` line.

Comment: This also works for macOS's /usr/bin/python3 (after installing Command Line Developer Tools), Python 3 from the python.org installer, and Homebrew's Python 3. It's not mentioned in the man page.

Answer (score 5):

Use [readline.parse_and_bind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#readline.parse_and_bind) method. For example, try on python interactive console:

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind("set editing-mode vi")
```

It seems any command you can set in .inputrc you can set via this method too. I tried it in Python 2.7 and 3.5.1.

See also `man readline`

---

**EDIT** *(Dec 21th, 2019)*: or maybe, to have a true vim you can manage to patch the python's readline with [Athame](https://github.com/ardagnir/athame). I did it with bash and it is very cool.

Answer (score -1):

On **macOS Monterey(12.5)** with **Python 3.10**, I got vi bindings to work in the python interpreter by adding `set editing-mode vi` to `~/.inputrc`(which I also created).

Comment: I tested this on macOS Sonoma with the Apple-supplied python3 (3.9), the official python.org 3.12 installer, and the Homebrew 3.12 python. It didn't work in any of them. Only putting "bind -v" in ~/.editrc worked.