# How do I make vi editing-mode work in IRB when using RVM?

Tags: rvm, vi, irb

I "`set editing-mode vi`" in my `.inputrc` on my Mac OS system, which allows vi editing in IRB. When I'm using a RVM Ruby, the IRB sessions don't process this directive.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you got `set -o vi` set, either at the command-line or in one of your startup scripts? That turns it on for the shell. I have both "`set editing-mode vi`" and `set -o vi` and have Vi-like editing in IRB.

---

EDIT:

Try creating `~/.editrc`, put `bind -v` in it. Snow Leopard has support for editline built in, so that might be what IRB is using.

Try `man 5 editrc` for more info.

Comment: Yes I have set -o vi in ~/.bashrc (well actually ~/.bash_profile), and I have vi editing on the command line before going into irb, but then inside irb, it just doesn't seem to process the ~/.inputrc file. This a pretty frustrating setback for me using rvm. I'm sure there is a solution. Someone recommended I try Readline.set_vi_editing (or some such command) but I got the error "not implemented on this machine". Mac Snow Leopard.

Comment: The ~/.editrc file worked. You're a genious. I love you. Swear to god. Wonder why the system irb used ~/.inputrc and the rvm irb uses ~/.editrc...

Comment: ~/.editrc worked for me as well, I'm running mountain lion. Thanks!

Comment: this also solve my issue -- however I ran into a problem using it: I had MORE than JUST "bind -v" in my ~/.editrc, which wasn't working. I removed everything else, leaving only "bind -v" and it works fine.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned before, you can add `bind -v` in your `~/.editrc`.

The problem with this, as you may or may not have noticed is that this removes your ability to use tab completion. If you want to keep tab completion you can add: `bind \\t rl_complete` to your
`~/.editrc`.

Comment: Putting `bind -v` into `~/.inputrc` didn't mess up my tab completion.  I am on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 7):

Using RVM-installed Ruby 1.9.3 on Mountain Lion, I was able to get vi key bindings in irb by adding `bind -v` to ~/.editrc .  I installed Ruby 2.0 using RVM on the same system and irb was stuck in emacs mode.  Adding `set editing-mode vi` to ~/.inputrc got vi key bindings working in irb on Ruby 2.0 for me.

Comment: I had similar experience with MAC OSX El Capitan, using Python3. Adding both bind -v to .editrc, and set editing-mode vi to inputrc worked.

Answer (score 3):

These days, I'm using rbenv-installed Ruby 2.5 on MacOS Mojave and the way to get vi key bindings in irb is to add `set editing-mode vi` to `~/.inputrc`.

It appears that  adding `bind -v` to `~/.editrc` isn't required and doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on BigSur (11.1) and observe this

- If using native ruby - edit ~/.editrc to add in 'bind -v'
- If using RVM built ruby - edit ~/.inputrc and add 'set editing-mode vi'

So you have to do both to make sure.  A method does not work for the other

Answer (score 0):

IRB (interactive Ruby shell) uses the [Readline](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) utility for line-editing capabilities.

Readline comes with a set of default keybindings. You can change these in the *inputrc* file. The location of this file defaults to `~/.inputrc`.

When IRB starts up, the *inputrc* file is read, and the key bindings are set.

To use vim editing mode add the following to your `~/.inputrc`

```sh
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command
```

Please consult the [documentation](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-inputrc.html) for other useful configuration options and where to put them.