# Are there vi / vim shortcuts available in pry or irb?

Tags: ruby, vim, vi, irb, pry

I have muscle memory of the vi/vim commands.  So in bash, I use the vi mode,
for example, I can easily go back to my command history and re-edit previous commands.

Are vi shortcuts available with pry or irb?  If so, how do I set it up?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make vi editing-mode work in IRB when using RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636124/how-do-i-make-vi-editing-mode-work-in-irb-when-using-rvm)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about re-editing previous commands, but you could use [interactive editor](https://github.com/jberkel/interactive_editor) gem to start vim-like editing from inside of your `irb`. Using that, you can start `irb`, edit your script in vim and let ruby shell execute it immediately. Here is a great tutorial on this: [Running Vim within IRB](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/running-vim-within-irb/).