# `set editing-mode vi` in Python readline (os x)

Tags: python, osx-lion, vi, readline

Trying to beef up my regular python console, I wanted to add vi-style editing.

1st thing: `python` is not reading `~/.inputrc` if I understand well.

Then, I tried to do (through `~/.pythonrc.py`):

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi')
```

Nothing's happening. Did I miss something? Or is it a problem with my terminal?

I'm on OS X using Terminal.app

(tried rlwrap with no success)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537522/standard-python-interpreter-has-a-vi-command-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `readline` modules in the Apple-supplied system Pythons in OS X do not link with the GNU `readline` library since Apple does not ship GNU `readline` with OS X (presumably because of license issues).  They do link with the BSD `editline` library, `libedit`, which reads `~/.editrc` and supports a different set of editing commands.  See `man 5 editrc` for details.  As documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html), you can check for the text `libedit` in `readline.__doc__` to determine whether GNU `readline` or BSD `editline` is in use.  If you really need GNU `readline`, you may be able to install the [`readline` package from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline) which has a pre-compiled version of the Python `readline` module linked with GNU `readline`.

Comment: readline vs editline is the thing, thanks. Finally I'm just adding `bind -v` in ~/.editrc and I'm done

Comment: I would recommend checking answers provided here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636124/how-do-i-make-vi-editing-mode-work-in-irb-when-using-rvm