# Why doesn't python 2.7.10 recognize my .pystartup and .inputrc?

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite

Following [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interactive.html) for my ~/.pystartup and adding `export PYTHONSTARTUP="~/.pystartup"` to my .bash_profile.  After I open a new terminal, and fire up python I get

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Could not open PYTHONSTARTUP
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.pystartup'
```

~/pystarup definitely exists.  I also would like vi key bindings and when I put `set editing-mode vi` in my ~/.inputrc, I still do NOT get the appropriate bindings.

I am working on OSX 10.10.5.  How do I fix these issues?

Comment: I'm not sure whether Python is as smart as BASH or any other shell to recognize `~/file` as `file` being stored in your home directory. Try to provide a full path to your `.pystartup` file.

Comment: Yes you are right on that.  That fixes my finding of the ~/.pystartup.  However that still leaves the mystery of why my vi key bindings don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comment helped the OP, I'm gonna copy it here: Python doesn't seem to recognize shell-specific features like `~` replaced with the Home directory, so it's better to manually replace `~` with the full path to the home directory in this case.

Speaking about `.inputrc` problems: Mac OS doesn't even use it. Instead, you should use your `~/.editrc`. So, you can run `man editor` to get more information. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/537633/4354477) for more information on this topic.