# How to set Python 3.9 interactive editor to Vim mode

Tags: python, interactive, read-eval-print-loop, python-3.9

In Python 2.7, when I opened Python interactively
with the `>>>` prompts, the commands it took were Vim style. I love that.

When I use Python 3.9 it doesn't and the editor is much more difficult to use.
How can I set it to Vim mode?

Comment: Check https://superuser.com/questions/1337199/how-to-make-vim-to-have-python-interactive-runtime-window

Comment: or potentially check `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537522/standard-python-interpreter-has-a-vi-command-mode`

Comment: What exactly do you mean "vim style"?  You have to press `i` every time before typing text?  You have to type `ZZ` to actually save the code?

Comment: You can try [this](https://github.com/ardagnir/athame)

Comment: Removed the Vim tag because Vim has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

The Python REPL uses either GNU readline or editline/libedit for user interaction. Both provide two sets of keybindings out of the box: `emacs` and `vi` (not Vim).

The former is set up with a `~/.inputrc` file:

- see `$ man readline` for information about the file and what to put in it to enable `vi` mode.

The latter is set up with a `~/.editrc` file:

- see `$ man editrc` for general information about the file,
- and `$ man editline` for what to put in it to enable `vi` mode.

If you are not sure which one is used just try one and see if it works. On macOS, it tends to be editline/libedit but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Actually... with python3, it seems to still use the ~/.inputrc
I set it as

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

and all is perfectly working now.